# "Прыгающее" меню при наведении на элементы

Tags: html, css

У меня есть меню с одним размером шрифта, и при наведении размер шрифта должен быть больше. Из-за этого "прыгают" остальные элементы меню.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
}

.main-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 7px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

.main-menu a {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #62a29e;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #528b86;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Contacts</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Как это можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 3):

Можно `li` увеличить (scale) без последствий

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}

.main-menu {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main-menu>li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 7px;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.main-menu a {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8125rem;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 12px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #62a29e;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #528b86;
  padding: 10px 12px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">About</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Portfolio</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Blog</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Features</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu__item">
    <a class="main-menu__link" href="#">Contacts</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите жесткие размеры всем ссылкам. Или под настоящими ссылками сделайте фейковые прозрачные, с уже увеличенным размером, а настоящие повесьте поверх абсолютом. Или уговорите заказчика не менять ничего, что влияет на размеры при наведении (размер шрифта, жирность и прочее), это лучший вариант.